# Unexpected nil variable in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a very basic RSpec example that doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Referral-type functionality" do
  describe "Affiliate system" do
    before { @affiliate = Affiliate.create(account_id: 1) }
    subject { @affiliate }

    describe "URL should work" do
      visit @affiliate.aff_url
    end

  end
end
```

When I run it, though, rspec gives a NoMethodError because @affiliate is nil. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instance variables defined in the `before` block are visible in the example block (`it`, `specify`) but not in the `describe` block. E.g.:

```
specify 'URL should work' do
  visit @affiliate.aff_url
end
```

Comment: So is it best practice here to just duplicate the before and subject blocks?

Comment: Best practice is controversial here. I prefer using the `let` statement for this.