# rspec @variable returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have an issue with my @attributes variable.  I would like it to be accessible to keep my code dry, but currently, I have to restate the variable and set it to "values" to get my rspec test to work. What is a better way to do this without duplicating the values.

ref: [Unexpected nil variable in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163885/unexpected-nil-variable-in-rspec)

Shows that it is not accessible in describe, but there needs be another solution. When would "specify" be appropriate? I have not used it.

```
describe "When one field is missing invalid " do 
    before(:each) do 
        @user = create(:user)
        @attributes = {"has_car"=>"true", "has_truck"=>"true", "has_boat"=>"true", "color"=>"blue value", "size"=>"large value"}
    end
  values = {"has_car"=>"true", "has_truck"=>"true", "has_boat"=>"true", "color"=>"blue value", "size"=>"large value"}
  values.keys.each do |f|
    p = values.except(f) 
    it "returns invalid when #{f.to_s} is missing" do 
              cr = CarRegistration::Vehicle.new(@user, p)
        cr.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

Update based on comments:
I would also like to use the values array hash in other tests.  If I put it in the loop as stated, I would still have to repeat it in other places.  Any other recommendations?

Update: I tried using let(),

```
  describe "When one field is missing" do

        let(:user) {Factorybot.create(:user)}
        let(:attributes) = {{"has_car"=>"true", "has_truck"=>"true", "has_boat"=>"true", "color"=>"blue value", "size"=>"large value"}}

      attributes do |f|
        p = attributes.except(f) 
        it "returns invalid when #{f.to_s} is missing" do 
                  cr = CarRegistration::Vehicle.new(user, p)
            cr.valid?
        end
      end
  end
```

but get the following error.

`attributes` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).

Comment: You can run the looping of the keys from INSIDE the it block,  that way you won't need to duplicate @attributes with the 'values' variable.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Any recommendations for reusing the keys outside of the bloc for other others too?

Comment: try using the let helper methods to allow reuse outside the block: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, I tried let and get the above error.

Comment: refer to my answer below or alternatively, follow sergio's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In either of your snippets, you don't need `attributes` **inside** of your specs. It is data to *generate* specs. As such, it must live one level above.

```
describe "When one field is missing" do

  let(:user) { Factorybot.create(:user) }

  attributes = { "has_car" => "true", "has_truck" => "true", "has_boat" => "true", "color" => "blue value", "size" => "large value" }

  attributes do |f|
    p = attributes.except(f)
    it "returns invalid when #{f.to_s} is missing" do
      cr = CarRegistration::Vehicle.new(user, p)
      cr.valid?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i accidentally edited this answer. please revert to original version. apologies.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: no worries :) JFYI, this approach (loop over a data structure and create several `it` blocks) is somewhat widely used. Makes crystal clear failure logs. Unlike your version ;) (which would produce "expected false to be true")

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: good point about the spec missing an actual assertion! Didn't notice.

Comment: you are 100% correct i've added a note for OP's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have recognized, based on the other SO post you linked to, you can't refer to your instance variables out in your describe block.  Just set it as a local variable as you've done.

Answer (score 0):

### Using let

```
describe "When one field is missing" do
  let(:user) {Factorybot.create(:user)}
  let(:attributes) = {{"has_car"=>"true", "has_truck"=>"true", "has_boat"=>"true", "color"=>"blue value", "size"=>"large value"}}
  ## The variables are used INSIDE the it block.
  it "returns invalid when a key is missing" do
    attributes do |f|
      p = attributes.except(f)
      cr = CarRegistration::Vehicle.new(user, p)
      expect(cr.valid?).to eq(true)  # are you testing the expectation? Added this line.    
    end
  end
end
```

Personally I don't like writing test (like the above) which could fail for multiple reasons. Sergio is correct. But if you want to use `let` you have to make use of it from WITHIN the `it` block - this example shows that.